# Error loading youtube video in modal dialog with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I created a modal dialog to play youtube videos in.  When the user clicks on a thumbnail image of the video it opens the dialog and injects the youtube iframe with this line of jQuery:

```
videoModal.html("<iframe class='youtube-player' id='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='640' height='385' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId + "?autoplay=1'  frameborder='0'></iframe>");
```

I get the following error only in Chrome, all other browsers do not complain

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://myDomain/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/MyVideoID?autoplay=1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Any ideas?  Should I be worried about this?  Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: I had difficulties using the YouTube JavaScript API while receiving this error.  Never confirmed a relationship, but it sounds about right.  I just used the alternative object embed code from the [generator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo).

Comment: @BradKoch You should post that as an answer, that was a huge help, completely fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the player works, and this is a JavaScript warning in the console, I wouldn't worry about it. It just means that some script inside the iframe (at youtube) is attempting to access its parent window, which happens to be on a different domain. Cross-domain security prevents this from working, but it shouldn't affect your page.