# Unsafe Javascript Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Youtube embed: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346176/youtube-embed-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame)

Basically, I get an error when I try to load an Iframe with a youtube link. It;s just a modal window. If you visit my page http://www.shannonhochkins.com/ and click on the "video thumbnail" up the top of the page. You'll cause the error.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.shannonhochkins.com/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/9PxYIijDIfA. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I don't really know how to go around this or why it's even popping up :(

Comment: This is flagged as Java because...?

Comment: It's harmless, and asked quite often: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Unsafe+JavaScript+attempt+to+access+frame+with+URL+youtube

Comment: Post your javascript that is showing the frame/video, odds are that is not what is causing the video not to show.