# JQuery youtube link to embedded doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/T6Nja/

My JQuery:

```
$('.training').html(function(i,v){
    var id = v.split('watch?v=')[1]; // get the id so you can add to iframe
    return '<iframe width="150" height="150" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
});
```

});
My HTML:

```
<div class="training">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DABphlXEyW8e</div><div class="training">http://youtu.be/DABphlXEyW8f</div>
```

Im clueless...

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What's wrong with the current results?

Comment: @james, its something with the id that makes the videos not play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the video id in the first div [look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/T6Nja/4/) where i've changed the video id from `DABphlXEyW8e` to `DABphlXEyW8`

Comment: +1 Didn't even notice the extra e/f on the ends.. They seem to cause a redirect back to DABphlXEyW8, which maybe what's causing the UnSafe JavaScript error.

Answer (score 0):

The first one does work (In the sense it gets the id from the url in the div), as it contains :

```
watch?v=
```

Which is needed in the extraction of the id on this line:

```
var id = v.split('watch?v=')[1]; // get the id so you can add to iframe
```

But it throws this error in jsfiddle:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
http://jsfiddle.net/T6Nja/ from frame with URL 
http://www.youtube.com/embed/DABphlXEyW8e.
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The second "training" `div` does not work because it does not contain the:

```
watch?v=
```

Needed to extract the Id

You need to update your html to be like this:

```
<div class="training">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DABphlXEyW8e</div>

<div class="training">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DABphlXEyW8f</div>
```

[Youtube embed: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346176/youtube-embed-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame)

The link above will help you out with your Unsafe JavaScript attempt